# Ionic2 - Close the alert/modal from different page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have 2 pages, home page and login page. In home page there is button when you press the button, it will popup and alert. Also in home page there is timer running it will logout (setroot to login page) you after certain time period.

Assume that user clicked on the button and popup appeared and waited for time interval to automatically navigate back to login page.

In this situation, i would like close the alert which i open on home page from login page.

I would appreciate all your help and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my issue is not able to close that alert from the login page.

Comment: Would it be satisfactory to use navigation guard to handle your logout logic? If not they I would suggest using a provider (service) that is shared between  both pages and call APIs to handle the popup.

Comment: Can you show your `code`?

Comment: Thanks Philip,  i just gave a example on my question. On the real project i have many alerts using AlertController inside private methods. What i am trying to do is dismiss all the alerts using ViewController if possible.

Comment: Hi Sampath, Please find the sample code :  
Private button_click(){

let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Alert',
        message: 'No changes to save.',
        buttons: [{
          text: 'OK',
          handler: () => {
            
          }
        }]
      });
      alert.present();


}


Login Page 
————————
Private closeAll_alerts(){

  
// I need solution here to close all alerts

}